# Is it possible to store uploaded pictures for OCR analysis in azure storage for later debugging and analysis?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, computer-vision, ocr, azure-cognitive-services

**Context**

I have an mobile app that provides our users with the possibility to capture the name plate of our products automatically. For this I use the Azure Cognitive Services OCR service.

I am a bit worried that customers might capture pictures of insufficient quality or of the wrong area of the product (where no name plate is). To analyse whether this is the case it would be handy to have a copy of the captured pictures so we can learn what went well or what went wrong.

**Question**

Is it possible to not only process an uploaded picture but to also store it in Azure Storage so that I can analyse it in a later point in time?

**What I've tried so far**

I configured the Diagnostic settings in a way that the logs and metrics are stored into Azure Storage. As it is called, this is only logs and metrics and not the actual image. So this does not solve my issue.

**Remarks**

- I know that I can manually implement that in the app but I think it would be better if I have to upload 
  the picture only once.
- I'm aware that there are data protection considerations that must be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't add an automatic logging based only on OCR operation, you have to implement it.

But to avoid uploading it twice as you said, you could create your logic on server side, but sending the image to your api and in the api, get the image and send it to OCR while storing it in parallel.

But I guess that based on your question, you might not have any server side things in your app?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Nicolas R. As you presume correctly, we do not have any server side functions running.